# Build fails when using methods from I/O Kit on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, build, iokit

I need to perform some operations in my C++ app upon sleep and wake up of Mac OS. I am being pointed to using I/O Kit.

I followed [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html), specifically "Listing 3". No build errors occurred with the `#include` directives for `IOKit`.

However, build fails when I uncomment `IOAllowPowerChange()` or `IOCancelPowerChange()`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOAllowPowerChange", referenced from:
      SleepCallback(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) in MyAppFrameWork.a(PowerWatcher.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried adding `IOKit.framework` in Project Settings > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries, which didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Same error occurs when using any method from I/O Kit, including: `IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource()` and `IORegisterForSystemPower()`.

No errors though when declaring variables, for example for `IONotificationPortRef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really should be solved by linking against IOKit.framework. Are you sure you added it to the right target? You need to link against it in the final executable or framework. Static libraries can't link against frameworks.

Comment: You're right, I added it to the wrong target, a framework.