# Cannot resolve osx compile error

Tags: c++, macos, iokit

I am trying to use IOKit library example for retrieving osx related system information as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn1103/_index.html

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_IOObjectRelease", referenced from: ...

"_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", referenced from: ...

"_IOServiceGetMatchingService", referenced from: ...

"_IOServiceMatching", referenced from: ...

"_kIOMasterPortDefault", referenced from: ...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using both "-framework CoreFoundation" and "-framework IOKit".

It is not duplicate because I had not linked it against wrong target, but I had typo :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build fails when using methods from I/O Kit on XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119627/build-fails-when-using-methods-from-i-o-kit-on-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `-framework IOKit` in the link command for your final executable file, or when linking a static library which you then link into your executable? Static libraries cannot link against dynamic libraries and frameworks themselves, you must do this at the executable or dylib (incl. bundles or frameworks) stage.

Comment: I had a typo in the variable that linked framework to the target

Comment: If you're trying to accept the question, there's a little tickbox under the answer score, which you can click.